# Python Server socket.error: [Errno 92] Protocol not available

Tags: python

I wanted to make a server, that recives an command from a client, in the form of a String and send a String(or a List of Strings) back.
The first time, I run the server and the client, it works perfectly fine, but after the server send the String to the client, the server crashes with the message:

```
socket.error: [Errno 92] Protocol not available
```

Here is the Server:

```
import socket
import errno


def Main():
    host = '192.168.178.30'
    port = 12345

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(1)


    while True:

        c, addr = s.accept()
        c.setblocking(0)

        print "Connection from: " + str(addr)


        command = c.recv(1024)

        if command == 'GIVETEXT':
            c.send('test')

        try:
            c.close()
            s.setsockopt(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 1)
        except socket.error as e:
            if e.errno != errno.ECONNRESET:
                raise
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

And Here is the client part:

```
import socket

class Client(object):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def sent(self, host, port):
        self.s.connect((host, port))
        self.s.send('GIVETEXT')#sends command

        self.Text = self.s.recv(1024)

        print self.Text

        self.s.close
        return self.Text
```

Comment: Which line fails exactly? Can you edit your question and add a full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the server code, could you comment (or remove) the following line:

```
s.setsockopt(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 1)
```

The setsockopt operation is to define the options of the socket. The level should be SOL_SOCKET and the differents options can be found in setsockopt man page:
http://linux.die.net/man/3/setsockopt

An example would be:

```
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it ended up being the `eventlet` library, which is only compatible with Linux Kernel versions >= 3.9. (As found in source code of this file: https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/blob/f9a3074a3b75f17f76cc04a693dc48a367b99861/eventlet/convenience.py which tried to run `sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)`).

In my case I was using Flask-SocketIO also was able to switch to `gevent`, which does not have this limitation.