# TCP connection state from RAW SOCKET packet sniffing

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

Here is my code:

```
ins = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, 3)
ins.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 2**30)
ins.bind((interface_name, 3))

while True:
    fmt = "B"*7+"I"*21
    pkt, sa_ll = self.ins.recvfrom(65535)
    x = struct.unpack(fmt, ins.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_INFO, 92))
    print "===>",x
    print "HEX Packet",hexlify(pkt)
    process_ipframe(sa_ll[2],hexlify(pkt))
```

Getting `socket.error: [Errno 92] Protocol not available` error. **Or is there any better way to get the TCP(Need only `ESTAB` connctions) states for the connections.**

Comment: Maybe, in this link you can find an answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514180/python-server-socket-error-errno-92-protocol-not-available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514180/python-server-socket-error-errno-92-protocol-not-available)

Comment: No, still it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my requirement is to get the established connections. But I was sniffing traffic on the interface for other purpose. So, I though I could get TCP states from raw sockets. But I found `/proc/net/tcp`: there is `st` field, from that I can get `ESTABLISHED` connections. So, I should read `/proc/net/tcp` continuously to get `ESTAB` for a specific time in different thread.

So, the answer is `/proc/net/tcp`. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992211/list-of-possible-internal-socket-statuses-from-proc). or may I should use `netfilter`